# How do i create a hangman timer such that it deducts the user's score every 10 seconds in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a timer such that it will deduct a value 1 from the user score for every 10s. But once i run the program and wait until the 30s mark to trigger the codes that i have written, the error below occurred . Is there a better way to do it?

```
def countdown():

    score=0
    stop_thread=True
    count=0
    while stop_thread and count<40:
        count=count+1
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if stop_thread:
        print("You took too long to guess. Your score is deducted by 1.")
        score=score-1
        if count==20:
            print("You took too long to guess again. Your score is deducted by 1 again.")
            score=score-1
    else:
        score=score
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the initial value of the score?

Comment: @Johnny sorry i didn't show. It is 0.

Comment: And stop_thread?

Comment: @Johnny my stop_thread is just stop_thread=true

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `score` before the whole logic, using whatever maximum value you wanted the student to have if he didn't take too much time:

```
score=0  # starts from 0
count=0
while stop_thread and count<40:
    count=count+1
    time.sleep(0.5)
if stop_thread:
    print("You took too long to guess. Your score is deducted by 1.")
    score=score-1
    if count==20:
        print("You took too long to guess again. Your score is deducted by 1 again.")
        score=score-1
else:
    score=score
```

Comment: but it doesn't continues to deduct even including the score=0..

Answer (score 0):

As @Arnaud said, you need to initialize the **score** variable before attempting to reference it.

But the larger issue is that you should consider using an asynchronous I/O (and timer) design rather than threading for this.  Design your program around a main event loop; and have that check for input, update the display, and check for other asynchronous events (timer expirations) while performing non-blocking operations or operations which only block on input for short intervals (like the those provided in the newer [selectors](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/selectors.html) or the older, lower level, [select](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/select.html) modules from the standard library, or from the [ascynio](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio.html) higher level system.

Of course you can do this with threads.  But even then you should have a main thread co-ordinating its activity through [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/queue.html) objects.  Have a priority queue into which you schedule timer events, and a thread which acts as a blocking consumer on that queue; it pops out timer events and produces other events for the main loop.  Then one or more input worker threads can block on input channels and feed input events into the main loop's event queue.  Now the main loop just updates the screen and consume events (telling it which updates to perform).

That main loop implements the state machine for the game.  Displaying the intro, playing the main game, handling these timer events, detecting win/loss conditions and displaying scores and options to loop back into the next round of the game as appropriate.

It's important to have a solid design when attempting to threads.  Coherent queues are incredibly useful as design primitives for multitasking and multithreading.

Comment: threads sounds  complicated  for someone like me who just start not long ago in python. Currently im using jupyter for my hangman programme so i suppose threads is still applicable in jupyter?  And what type of suitable queue objects should i add in if thats the case?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read the question.  I thought you were already trying to do this with some threading logic (not shown in the code snippet).  So, yes.  Just initialize your variables before you try to "reference" them ... that is before you attempt to do anything depending on their prior value  such as ***score=score-1*** or, more idiomatically: ***score -= 1*** (augmented assignment).

Comment: but the problem i am facing is that after initializing the variable score=0,it doesn't continues to deduct after 10 seconds as shown in my attempt for if count==20: onwards...

Comment: So you're initializing these variables in your function definition.  But that means that your re-initializing them for each invocation of the function.  They're not retaining their values between calls.  This function should probably be a class, or you should pass and return a mutable object (dictionary) to maintain the state between one call (invocation) and the next.